# Team Foundation 2010 beta - get rid of unused fields (Migration plan)

Tags: tfs, migration

Downloading it now and was wondering if anyone else has moved an existing Custom process template (Work Items types, work items and source control) to the beta.

Over the past few years our custom process template has "evolved" and I know it has unused fields in it. Do you think if I set up another server added our custom process template, would I be able to move over our existing work items, and source as a test? we will be keeping 2008 for daily development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your new server instance you would be able to move over a copy of the latest version of files from version control and migrate your work items by taking the new version of the process templates and putting in the fields that you need and then adding the data for the current work items (I usually use Excel to do a bulk import).  You will loose history for both Version Control and Work Item Tracking however.

When TFS2010 ships, I'd expect there to be guidance for people wanting to update their existing templates to have new functionality and integrate with the new test work items etc.

Comment: You just use Excel!?? But..but..but you are ..gasp..Martin Woodward :) Kinda thought, of all people, a TFS god like you migrated by snapping fingers or wiggling your nose.

Comment: I must admit I agree that I thought Excel to be rather mundane way to migrate for a larger than life TFS person like Martin Woodward :)  (By the way, I LOVE Radio TFS!)